# which word should I use for [export to] in IT/software environment

Tags: word-choice

Usually I use エクスポート for export.
But that word is too long to be used in some cases.
For example, text inside the button.
「EXCELにエクスポート」

Which other word I can use in such case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Japanese, there are several words that can be used as a shorter alternative to エクスポート (export) depending on the context. Here are some options:

1. 出力する (shutsuryoku suru) - This means "to output." It can be used to refer to exporting data or files in various formats.
2. 書き出す (kakidasu) - This means "to write out" or "to export." It can be used for exporting text or data in general.

In the specific example of "EXCELにエクスポート" (export to Excel), you could use any of the above options to create a shorter button label:

・「Excelに出力」
・「Excelに書き出し」